# View transition at animation end

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Here's the deal:

I have an image and a button on my mobile app's homeview.

I apply an animation to the image by pressing the button. That works great.

**PROBLEM:**

I want to add a view transition that pushes to the next view after the animation completes.

**CODE:**

AS:

```
    protected function nextView()
    {
    navigator.pushView(View2);
    }
```

MXML:

```
    <s:Button id="Button" click="anim.play()"/> //anim.play() is in 
    //the declarations tag and is working as expected.

    <s:Image id="img" source="@Embed('assets/image.png')"/>
```

**I've Tried:**

-Adding `nextView()` to the click method after the animation call

-Using `effectEnd="nextView()"` in Button properties

Thank you for any help and insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

effectEnd appears to work for me:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"> 
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Move id="myEffect" xBy="100" target="{btn}" effectEnd="navigator.pushView(NextView)" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:ViewNavigator id="navigator" width="100%" height="100%"/>

    <s:Button id="btn" label="play" click="myEffect.play()" />

</s:Application>
```